# Transposing the table with DATE Values and count values while duplicating rows

Tags: powerbi, etl, powerquery

I am trying to automate some raw excel file that comes into PBI, but I have to duplicate and transpose the values. The goal is for each value in Column1 to get count by month, where I have last date of the month as a value.

Thanks!

Here is raw data:

[image: Raw data]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the table into Power Query, then you can select all the date columns and unpivot (Transform tab) them to get the shape you're wanting.